# Como faço pra pegar o tamanho da janela redimensionada pelo usuário?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando usar um script pra fazer uma imagem sumir caso o tamanho da janela redimensionada seja menor que 400px de largura, porém não está funcionando...

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
if($(window).width() < 400) {
$('#facebook, #youtube').hide();
} else {    
$('#facebook, #youtube').show();
}
});
</script>
```

Sempre que eu uso um alert no console, ele retorna 980px mesmo se eu redimensionar a janela...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só quer que isso aconteça caso a janela 'sofra' resize? Também devia apanhar o evento de resize da janela:

```
function hide_show(width_window) {
   if(width_window < 400) {
      $('#facebook, #youtube').hide();
   } else {    
      $('#facebook, #youtube').show();
   }
}

// Fazemos isto sempre, mesmo quando não tiver havido ainda o resize da janela
var width_window = $(window).width();
// apagar esta linha abaixo caso só queira que isso aconteça no resize
hide_show(width_window);

// aqui apanhamos o evento resize do browser, e escrevemos o que queremos que aconteça quando se faz resize da janela
$(window).on('resize', function() {
   width_window = $(window).width();
   hide_show(width_window);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa referenciar o objeto de qual quer a largura. No caso, você quer a largura do objeto `window`, mas no seu código a única referência é do `document`. Fica assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();

  console.log(windowWidth);
  if (windowWidth < 361) {
    console.log('Tá menor');
  } else {
    console.log('Tá maior');
  }
});
```